# How to call <li> tag CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a website in which the html code is as below:

```
<div id="navmenu"><a id="home" href="http://www.abc.com" ><span>HOME<span></a>
<a id="about" href="http://www.abc.com/about-us/"><span>ABOUT US</span></a>
<ul class="about-child">
           <li><a href="#">Hard Drives1</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Hard Drives<2/a></li>
 </ul>
```

I want to call these ul and li tags to create CSS but I dont know how to style li and ul using CSS because I am using separate CSS tags for Home and About.

Comment: What "to call something using CSS" means?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by calling something with CSS, but if you want to add styles to the <li> tags you have in your code, just do this:
.about-child li { your styles here }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to select all the `<li>` tags, use this:

```
li {... css rules ...}
```

If you need to select all the `<li>` tags inside the `<ul class="about-child">`, use this:

```
ul.about-child li {... css rules ...}
```

If you need to select all the `<li>` tags inside any `<ul>` tag, use this:

```
ul li {... css rules ...}
```

And to include the **stylesheet**, you can either include it via `<link>`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
```

Or by embedding the stylesheet in your document:

```
<style type="text/css">
    li {... css rules ...}
    ul.about-child li {... css rules ...}
    ul li {... css rules ...}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

To target the ul: `ul.about-child { ... }`
To target the li's: `ul.about-child li { ... }`

If that doesn't help, I can't provide any more detailed information without knowing more about your problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can load an external css file by adding a link int head of your document:

```
<html>
  <head>
    ....
    <link href="yourcssfile.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

or you can use a style tag:

```
<style type="text/css">
  ... your css here ...
</style>
```

This is the code you will write to style this li tag

```
ul.about-child li {
   ... your css rules here...
}
```

Example:

```
<style type="text/css">
ul.about-child li {
    list-style-type: disc;
    font-size:18px;
}
</style>
```